# How to load only the content area, skip header and footer loading again in new pages over clicking links

Tags: javascript, php, html, stack-overflow, basecamp

Im using Basecamp, and when I click on the menu links, it just loads the inner body content alone, but still the URL changes, I wonder, Ive examined in network tab, and I see there for each link click it triggers an request and it only gets body part, no headers/footer are loading, amazed with the flow.

Where as in other sites(even in stackoverflow) it loads the page from the beginning, but with cache or some other stuff it loads quickly but there is a lil flicker if we could examine clearly.

Do you guys have any idea how it works, are there any frameworks that helps this way? because this really works extremely fast and no flicker at all in header menus, and specially while browsing in mobile it gives a feel like using an application(mobile app that loads just the content)

Please let me if you have any idea how this flow works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont understand why people downvote  :(, Not exposing my frustration, please understand, its my doubt, and this is the place where we share our knowledge, if you know just let me know the info,else wait for some one else who can explain, if you cant explain you are in same boat along with me then why you prefer downvoting, so do you blame yourself for unknowing the reason? Im sure many have this question, if my asking way is poor then suggest edits, Just clicking Downvote is not the right way to join a knowledge sharing culture. Im sorry if it hurts, but this is what I feel :)

Comment: Downvotes are just as important as upvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a full explanation](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui) of why this is so fast:

1. Stacker: a Turbolinks/PJAX technique for instant page loads
2. Russian-doll caching: a low-hassle, automated way to do aggressive caching